# This raphael graphics demo wouldn't run on jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, raphael

I've been trying to replicate [this](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/ichart.html) Raphael demo with out any success.
Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p1cw3yug/6/). I've copied the html and javascript by doing view-source. Also I've added the appropriate library in the resources and the css is also good. What am I missing ? Greatly appreciate any help. Thanks! Wow it seems it is working here in stackexchange environment, but still it is not working in jsfiddle. I feel I'm missing something terribly simple at jsfiddle. Any help ?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var W = 640,
    H = 480,
    r = Raphael("holder", W, H),
    values = [],
    len = 7;
  for (var i = len; i--;) {
    values.push(50);
  }

  function translate(x, y) {
    return [
      50 + (W - 60) / (values.length - 1) * x,
      H - 10 - (H - 20) / 100 * y
    ];
  }

  function drawPath() {
    var p = [];
    for (var j = 1, jj = X.length; j < jj; j++) {
      p.push(X[j], Y[j]);
    }
    p = ["M", X[0], Y[0], "R"].concat(p);
    var subaddon = "L" + (W - 10) + "," + (H - 10) + ",50," + (H - 10) + "z";
    path.attr({
      path: p
    });
    sub.attr({
      path: p + subaddon
    });
  }

  var p = [
      ["M"].concat(translate(0, values[0]))
    ],
    color = "hsb(240°, 1, 1)",
    X = [],
    Y = [],
    blankets = r.set(),
    buttons = r.set(),
    w = (W - 60) / values.length,
    isDrag = -1,
    start = null,
    sub = r.path().attr({
      stroke: "none",
      fill: [90, color, color].join("-"),
      opacity: 0
    }),
    path = r.path().attr({
      stroke: color,
      "stroke-width": 2
    }),
    unhighlight = function() {};
  var ii;
  for (i = 0, ii = values.length - 1; i < ii; i++) {
    var xy = translate(i, values[i]),
      xy1 = translate(i + 1, values[i + 1]),
      f;
    X[i] = xy[0];
    Y[i] = xy[1];
    (f = function(i, xy) {
      buttons.push(r.circle(xy[0], xy[1], 5).attr({
        fill: color,
        stroke: "none"
      }));
      blankets.push(r.circle(xy[0], xy[1], w / 2).attr({
        stroke: "none",
        fill: "#fff",
        opacity: 0
      }).mouseover(function() {
        if (isDrag + 1) {
          unhighlight = function() {};
        } else {
          buttons.items[i].animate({
            r: 10
          }, 200);
        }
      }).mouseout(function() {
        if (isDrag + 1) {
          unhighlight = function() {
            buttons.items[i].animate({
              r: 5
            }, 200);
          };
        } else {
          buttons.items[i].animate({
            r: 5
          }, 200);
        }
      }).drag(function(dx, dy) {
        var start = this.start;
        start && update(start.i, start.p + dy);
      }, function(x, y) {
        this.start = {
          i: i,
          m: y,
          p: Y[i]
        };
      }));
      blankets.items[blankets.items.length - 1].node.style.cursor = "move";
    })(i, xy);
    if (i == ii - 1) {
      f(i + 1, xy1);
    }
  }
  xy = translate(ii, values[ii]);
  X.push(xy[0]);
  Y.push(xy[1]);

  drawPath();
  var update = function(i, d) {
    (d > H - 10) && (d = H - 10);
    (d < 10) && (d = 10);
    Y[i] = d;
    drawPath();
    buttons.items[i].attr({
      cy: d
    });
    blankets.items[i].attr({
      cy: d
    });
    r.safari();
  };
};
```

```html
<script src="http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/raphael.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="holder"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Fixed the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/p1cw3yug/8/ 1) javascript load type is set to "Onload" by default, you need to change that to "no wrap" 2) the script URL was an `http` one but jsfiddle uses `https` and thus the browser refuses to load the script (as is clearly mentioned in the console, btw)

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you so much. You're just amazing! I'm new to jsfiddle, but I'll keep in mind to look at console from now on. If you convert above comment  to answer I'd love to mark it best answer :)

Comment: @ChrisG where to find the  javascript load type setting ?

Comment: Nvm found it !!